# Rust: Split a string to get both words and their positions

Tags: rust

Rust has built-in function to split a string around whitespace, something like:

```
let mut iter = " Hello world".split_whitespace();

assert_eq!(Some("Hello"), iter.next());
assert_eq!(Some("world"), iter.next());
```

However, I would like a way to split the string into words, with their corresponding position in the string.

```
let mut iter = ??????(" Hello world");

assert_eq!(Some((1, "Hello")), iter.next());
assert_eq!(Some((7, "world")), iter.next());
```

I have absolutely no idea where to start, given that:

- the built-in `split` and `split_whitespace` functions "consume" the whitespace, so I have no idea how much whitespace appears before a given element. Should I start from `split('')`, and somehow "group" the non whitespace together ?
- there is a [`match_indices`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.match_indices) function that does something similar, but it can only look for a given string, or for a char (using a closure.)

Is there something built-in for that ? Or do I need to iterate over an `std::str::Chars` iterator ?

If so, how would I go from a `Chars` iterator at a given character, to a String that represents the next word ? Is there a safe way to return it from a function ? (the compiler has never let me do it, so far)

Comment: "there is a match_indices function that does something similar, but it can only look for a given string, or for a char (using a closure.)" pattern can be a char alone too. anyway what the problem with match_indices ?

Comment: As far as I read the doc for `match_indices`, it does not let you ask for `split the string by all group of any nonwhitespace, and give me each group with the index of the first element of the group`. Or can it ?

Comment: well I never used match_indices... I don't think it's very used, if you want to do real parsing I advice use nom 6

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could make use of the fact that `split_whitespace()` returns slices that point into the original slice, and calculate the required indices as distances of the original slice's address from that of each subslice:

```
fn addr_of(s: &str) -> usize {
    s.as_ptr() as usize
}

fn split_whitespace_indices(s: &str) -> impl Iterator<Item = (usize, &str)> {
    s.split_whitespace()
        .map(move |sub| (addr_of(sub) - addr_of(s), sub))
}

fn main() {
    let mut iter = split_whitespace_indices(" Hello world");

    assert_eq!(Some((1, "Hello")), iter.next());
    assert_eq!(Some((7, "world")), iter.next());
}
```

Comment: I think this will fail for unicode characters (e.g. "λello world").

Comment: @lpiepiora there is no reason it's would fail why do you think that ? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bd71e2100b7368caf89d5e42ec5afca7

Comment: @lpiepiora It won't fail, it will return byte indices. This is consistent with other functions that return indices into a string, such as `char_indices()` and `match_indices()`, and is what slicing operations on `str` expect.

Comment: You are right, OP was writing about chars so I thought he wanted to count those. Neat solution btw.

Comment: You're right, it will "work" for non-ascii utf8 characters, although, as pointed out in the `chars_indices` doc, the indices might not be what you expect. I'll do it this way since I'm only parsing ascii ; for full utf8 support, I understand that I would need to use external crates like [unicode-segmentation](https://unicode-rs.github.io/unicode-segmentation/unicode_segmentation/trait.UnicodeSegmentation.html#tymethod.split_word_bound_indices)

Comment: @phtrivier In this case I believe there is no justification for scare quotes around work. The indices returned are the indices you need to obtain the substrings from the original string using the usual slicing operations, so they're perfectly correct for any code points. `char_indices()` docs doesn't warn about the indices, but about **characters** produced by the iterator, which are always individual code points rather than graphemes. This function doesn't split the string into individual code points, but into substrings only separated by whitespace, so it just doesn't have that issue.

Comment: Sure, the quotes were not to "scare" anyone, but to acknowledge the fact that the behavior, though technically correct and expected, can be a bit counter-intuitive (which is not a new question, of course.)

Comment: @phtrivier Just to clarify in case you're not a native speaker, "scare quotes" is an English idiom. I didn't mean to imply that you were literally attempting to scare someone. :)

Comment: Fair enough ;) !